# Extract date string from (more) complex string (possibly a regex match)

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string template that looks like `'my_index-{year}'`. 
 
I do something like  `string_template.format(year=year)` where year is some string. Result of this is some string that looks like `my_index-2011`.

Now. to my question. I have a string like `my_index-2011` and my template `'my_index-{year}'` What might be a slick way to extract the `{year}` portion?

[Note: I know of the existence of [`parse library`](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this module called [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) which provides an opposite to `format()` functionality:

> Parse strings using a specification based on the Python format() syntax.

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> s = "my_index-2011"
>>> f = "my_index-{year}"
>>> parse(f, s)['year']
'2011'
```

---

And, an alternative option and, since you are extracting a year, would be to use the [`dateutil` parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) in a fuzzy mode:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("my_index-2011", fuzzy=True).year
2011
```

Comment: I didn't know about the dateutil parser. Nice note. I was a little iffy about installing a new package for just this one functionality, and was wondering if there was a nifty `re.match(..)` way of doing this. But yea. Seems like I'll just stick to using the parse module. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split()` string function to split the string into two parts around the dash, then grab just the second part.

```
mystring = "my_index-2011"
year = mystring.split("-")[1]
```

Comment: Good answer. I thought of that. Something like this would break as soon as the year became a time or the formatting changed or something of that sort. I wanted to focus on using just the template to get the year part out. If you check the link, the [parse module](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) does a good job at this. I just dont want to install a new library for just this, and was wondering if there was a slick way of achieving the same result. Regardless, a +1 for you. :)

Comment: @DebosmitRay _Something like this would break as soon as the year became a time_ Why?  As long as the basic pattern remains intact (i.e. the target portion of the string comes after a dash), `split()` will continue to work just fine.  (If the target portion itself contains dashes, you can tell `split()` to only split on the _first_ dash.)

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. Say, I decide to replace this with 'my-index'. The template changed, but our function, having not used it, broke. Again, this is for a healthy debate to see if there is a good answer. I am pretty sure this cannot have a "correct" answer haha

Comment: @DebosmitRay If the string template can change, I'm not sure any solution would be foolproof...

Answer (score 2):

I assume "year" is 4 digits and you have multiple indexes

```
import re
res = ''
patterns = [ '%s-[0-9]{4}'%index for index in idx ] 
for index,pattern in zip(idx,patterns):
    res +=' '.join( re.findall(pattern ,data) ).replace(index+'-','') + ' '
```

---update---

```
dummyString = 'adsf-1234 fsfdr lkjdfaif ln ewr-1234 adsferggs sfdgrsfgadsf-3456'
dummyIdx = ['ewr','adsf']
```

output

```
1234 1234 3456
```

Comment: Why do we need the for loop in this approach?

Comment: Like. I think this is a decent idea. But, its overkill to be honest. That loop with a `+=` on a string is bad for performance, as is using re.match in a loop. +1 for the answer for the effort, though.

Comment: @DebosmitRay agree. if you have pattern for your indexes, it can also be regax. for example, if the format always like 5 letters plus "-" plus 4 digits index-1234 = > pattern = r'\d{5}-\d{4}', therefore no need loop all the indexes. my first assumption is all the indexes are unique

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a regex would be helpful here.

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = 'my_string-2014'
In [3]: print( re.search('\d{4}', s).group(0) )
2014
```

Edit: I should have mentioned your regex can be more sophisticated.  You can haul out a subcomponent of a more specific string, for example:

```
In [4]: print( re.search('my_string-(\d{4})$', s).group(1) )
2014
```

Given the problem you presented, I think any "find the year" formula should be expressible in terms of a regular expression.

Comment: I like the idea behind this one. Its kind of like using the length of the 'needle' to get the result. Always enjoyed going over [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#simulating-scanf). +1

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use the [string method `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split on "-", and then catch the last element as your year:

```
year = "any_index-2016".split("-")[-1]
```

Because you caught the last element (using -1 as the index), your index can have hyphens in them, and you will still extract the year appropriately.

Comment: I have already addressed this in John Gordon's answer. There are multiple ways of breaking this.

Comment: For example. Year changed to time of the format `hh-mm`